# MongoDB Tailable Cursors in C#

Tags: mongodb

How to create a tailable cursor on a mongodb capped collection with the C# driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this feature is currently implemented in the C# driver.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-219

You should be able to add a watch to that item which will let you know when it's done.

Comment: This feature was implemented today. There's no documentation yet, but the JIRA ticket has a link to a sample program. The main thing about tailable cursors is that you can't consume them in a regular foreach loop, you have to get the enumerator yourself and call MoveNext and Current (along with some other requirements). See the sample program.

Comment: Thanks thats great! One thing I've not been able to grok on the c++ example or your example is, it would appear the initial find by _id is not going to use an index, since capped collections don't have that index by default. Is this just expected overhead to restart the cursor once it's dead or am I not understanding the performance impact of this?